# PHP: how to properly use return statements

Tags: php

Problem: I have a class called 'user' and a function called 'registerUser'. I want to send a successful registration to a page but an unsuccessful registration to a different page.

I have not filled out the return statement because that is where i am unsure if that is how i can fix the problem. I am new to php and believe that could work but as i said, i am new and still learning.

```
class User {
    function registerUser($userName, $userPassword) {
    // Connect to database
    $dbLink = mysql_connect($this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass);
    if(!$dbLink) die("Could not connect to database. " . mysql_error());

    // Select database
    mysql_select_db($this->dbName);

    // Insert data
    $query = "insert into $this->dbUserTable values (NULL, \"$userName\", \"$userPassword\")";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    // Test to make sure query worked
    if(!$result) {
        return(false);
    }

    // Get the user ID
    $this->userID = mysql_insert_id();

    // Close database connection
    mysql_close($dbLink);

    // Assign the values to the data members
    $this->userName = $userName;
    $this->userPassword = $userPassword;
    return(true);
} // End registerUser()
}
```

My php code that calls this class is simple.

```
    <?
// processRegister.php
//////////////////////

// First include the class definition
include('UserClass.php');

// Next, create an instance of the class
$newUser = new User;

// Call the registerUser() method, passing in the required variables
if ($newUser->registerUser($userName, $userPassword)) {
  header('Location: www.google.com');
} 
else {
  header('Location: www.yahoo.com.com');
}
?>
```

any help is much appreciated!

Comment: There's no returning from the dead!

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like so:

```
if ($newUser->registerUser($userName, $userPassword)) {
  $newUser->displayUserInfo();
} else {
  echo "Errors, ahoy!"
}
```

Get rid of your `die()` statements and just add `return false` (or replace `die` with `echo` and add `return false`, if you want debug messages).

At the *very* end, add `return true`.

Comment: i have updated the questions with my new code but it is not working, do you see any errors? i cant see any :(

Comment: it is sending me to my 404 page

Comment: You have an extra `.com` in your redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should return the last inserted user id by using the PHP function `mysql_insert_id()`. Based on this you can identifu if the register process was successful or not.

```
class User {
function registerUser($userName, $userPassword) {
        // Connect to database
        $dbLink = mysql_connect($this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass);
        if(!$dbLink) die("Could not connect to database. " . mysql_error());

        // Select database
        mysql_select_db($this->dbName);

        // Insert data
        // Notice the "$userName" and "$userPassword" - these are the ones
        // passed in from your main script, not the class/object variables!
        $query = "insert into $this->dbUserTable values (NULL, \"$userName\", \"$userPassword\")";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        return mysql_insert_id();

}
```

processRegister.php

```
<?
// processRegister.php
//////////////////////

// First include the class definition
include('UserClass.php');

// Next, create an instance of the class
$newUser = new User;

// Call the registerUser() method, passing in the required variables
$user_id = $newUser->registerUser($userName, $userPassword);

if(intval($user_id) && $user_id>0){
    //redirect to success page
}else{
    //redirect to error page
}

?>
```